# ServiceId.UniqueId Maximum Length and Format

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Every [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) (e.g. [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.task%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)) in Exchange Web Services (EWS) Managed API has an `Id` property of type [`ItemId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemid%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), which then has a `String` property named [`UniqueId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.serviceid.uniqueid%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) (inherited from [`ServiceId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd635957%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) — phew, got that?).

I'm planning to keep the value of `UniqueId` in a database so I need to know what the maximum length of the column should be. Some testing shows that it's at least `152` bytes in length, but that seems like a strange size for a maximum.

A second part to this question is the format of the value.  Is this something that can be parsed into a more common type, like a [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)? I'm grasping at straws, I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be safe, we've suggested [setting aside 512 characters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2012/04/03/ews-item-identifier-and-your-database.aspx)  for the EWS identifier. While I don't expect that it will ever be lengthened to near 512 characters, Microsoft reserves the right to change the format. I highly doubt Exchange will change the format at this point.

Regarding the format of the identifier -- it is intended to be opaque and so it should be neither parsed nor reconstructed.

Comment: So do you recommend storing it as Varbinary, Varchar, Uniqueidentifier?

Answer (score 4):

From [EWS Identifiers in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_WorkingWithIdentifiers):

- The ItemID element value for folders and items is case-sensitive. If you look at the item ID for a folder or item that is returned by the FindItem operation (or the FindItems EWS Managed API method), you might think that it is a duplicate of another item ID; however, one or more characters in the item IDs for the two items will have a different case.
- If you are going to store the item ID in a database to retrieve later, we recommend that the field size be 512 bytes, so that it’s large enough to hold the GUID.
- Don’t assume that your ID will always be valid if you need to retrieve the item at a later time. If an item is moved in the store, the ID can change because of the way a move is handled. An item is actually copied, and a new ID is generated, and then the original item is deleted.