# Max length of iCalUId

Tags: exchange-server, microsoft-graph-api

when creating events in outlook calendar you get a few ids to help "track" the event, I have a database and want to store `iCalUId` like so: `KalenderEventId nvarchar(max) null` but I can't find the max length of that object. What is the length of `iCalUId`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2012/04/03/ews-item-identifier-and-your-database/):

> (...) the EWS item identifier should be contained in a fixed-width column of 512 characters

Also also stated in the same post, we might expect EWS identifier length to **not** be changed (do not consider it as set in stone but rather *very unlikely to be changed*).

From [docs directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-identifiers-in-exchange#bk_WorkingWithIdentifiers):

- If you are going to store the item ID in a database to retrieve later, we recommend that the field size be 512 bytes, so that it's large enough to hold the GUID.

---

[Related question (but more general)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15770929/9902555)